# Call Javascript method from code behind c#

Tags: javascript, sharepoint, sharepoint-2010

Please help me solve this challenge:(
I have below code:

```
Label lblVideoAssessment = new Label();
                        lblVideoAssessment.Text = "<a href='../SitePages/Assessment.aspx?cat=" + cat + "' height='300px' width='300px' Target='_blank' cssClass='IconDisplayCss'><img src='~/_layouts/images/Assessment.png' border='none'/></a><br/>" + cat;
```

I want to replace above code by a dialogue box instead of opening a new page "Ässessment.aspx".
I have tried like this:

```
lblVideoAssessment.Text = "<a cssclass='IconDisplayCss' width='300px' height='300px' onclick='javascript:OpenDialog('../SitePages/Assessment.aspx?cat='+cat+);return false;'><img border='none' src='~/_layouts/images/Assessment.png'></a>";
```

However it doesnot work.
I think the issue is with the `''`(Quotation which i have placed ) or do i need to use Page.ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript

if yes...how and where do i place it?

Please help as i have been struggling for fort night.

I had also got suggestion to use Literal Control.I have tried that as well and it does not work.

Answer (score 1):

```
var strScript = "<script language=\"JavaScript\" type=\"text/javascript\">";
strScript += "alert(\"hello\")";
strScript += "</script>";
Page.ClientScript.RegisterClientScriptBlock(GetType(), "onload", strScript, false);
```

Good Luck!

Edit:

```
var script = "<script language=\"JavaScript\" type=\"text/javascript\">$('#tag').click(function () {})</script>"; Page.ClientScript.RegisterClientScriptBlock(GetType(), "ready", script , false);
```

Finally:

```
var script = "<script language=\"JavaScript\" type=\"text/javascript\">$(\".IconDisplayCss\").click(function () {OpenDialog('../SitePages/Assessment.aspx?cat='" + cat + "); });</script>" Page.ClientScript.RegisterClientScriptBlock(GetType(), "ready", script , false);
```

Comment: Here the AlertBox appears in on Pageload but i want on anchor tag clickevent, the javascript method should occur how to do...?if you can see the code above from question.

Comment: var script = "$('#tag').click(function () {})";
Page.ClientScript.RegisterClientScriptBlock(GetType(), "ready", script , false);

Comment: var script = "<script language=\"JavaScript\" type=\"text/javascript\">$(\".IconDisplayCss\").click(function () {OpenDialog('../SitePages/Assessment.aspx?cat='" + cat + "); });</script>"
Page.ClientScript.RegisterClientScriptBlock(GetType(), "ready", script , false);